# itk image convert to vtkimagedata

Tags: vtk, itk, medical

I'm trying to read a DICOM image with ITK reader then convert it into vtkimagedata for rendering.

As I convert ITK image with "itk::ImageToVTKImageFilter" and render it in vtkrenderwindow, the origin of this volume is set at center of this volume. How can I do to set the coordinate of render window same to the DICOM image?

Here's my code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> vtkImg = ITKconnectVTK(itkImg);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> ITKconnectVTK(ImageType::Pointer inputImg)
{
    ConnectorType::Pointer connector = ConnectorType::New();
    connector->SetInput(inputImg);
    connector->Update();

    return connector->GetOutput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which does just that:
https://itk.org/Wiki/VTK/ExamplesBoneYard/Cxx/VolumeRendering/itkVtkImageConvert

And another one which does not need an image:
https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/WishList/IO/itkVtkImageConvertDICOM

Comment: Thanks for recommend. I used itk flip function to flip the y and z-axis. Then apply vtkimagedata->setOrigin to set the origin as VTKDICOMReader dose.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the direct dicom series in the VTK, and if you need some filter send the image to itk and then get it again.

reading with vtk:
https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOM

convert from itk to vtk:
https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ImageToVTKImageFilter

convert from vtk to itk
https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Broken/Images/VTKImageToImageFilter

you need to enable itkvtkglue in itk for this.